# Automatizar envío de correos electrónicos cada X periodo de tiempo

Tags: php, laravel, script

estoy desarrollando una aplicación con **Laravel 9.X** en la que ya he creado un flujo de usuario, en el que se puede registrar, e interactuar con la página. Cuando un usuario se registra, le envía un correo electrónico para verificar su cuenta.

También tengo implementados los correos electrónicos en distintos sitios de mi aplicación.

Lo que estoy intentando realizar, es que una vez un usuario se registre, y pasen por ejemplo dos semanas, la aplicación le envíe un correo electrónico con una encuesta para ver que le parece.

He probado a utilizar la función `sleep()` de php, pero me temo que no funciona como me gustaría.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto con `php` o debo de crear un script y que la ejecute mi servidor?

Comment: Deberás crear un script que revise para cada usuario si han pasado dos semanas desde que se registro en la aplicación basándose en la fecha en la que se creó la cuenta y envíe el correo cuando sea necesario. Este script deberá ejecutarse cada X tiempo que decidas adecuado y deberás ejecutarlo mediante un `cronjob`

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores eso es lo que tenía en mente, pero me preguntaba a ver si existe alguna manera de hacerlo con laravel. Sino, lo que había pensado es crear un script que llame a una ruta a la que yo defina de laravel y ahí hacer todo lo que necesite.

Comment: Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido a mí. Lo que comentas de hacerlo con una ruta definida de Laravel no lo he probado pero supongo que funcionará así que puedes probarlo de esa manera, eso sí, deberías añadirle algún tipo de token de seguridad para que no se ejecute desde cualquier parte de la aplicación sino solo a través del `cron`

Comment: Te adjunto una pregunta muy parecida a la tuya que quiza pueda ayudarte: [method to send a weekly email to all users in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260756/method-to-send-a-weekly-email-to-all-users-in-laravel)

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores lo que me has comentado del `cron`, intuyo que es lo del `scheduling` que plantean [VFG](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/278458/vfg), pero en cuanto a lo de la seguridad que me has puesto, como lo debería de implementar, o si creo esto correctamente debería funcionar correctamente? Gracias

Comment: @Maidagan yo me refería al cron desde el propio servidor pero por lo que he podido ojear del `scheduling` que propone parece bastante similar, algo así como un `cron` interno. Así que sí es algo bastante similar si no igual y lo puedes probar a hacer de esta manera.

Comment: Voy a probar primero con `scheduling`, ya que es la opción que proporciona laravel, en caso de que me funcione o no, os lo iré comentando para ver que consigo. Gracias a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maidagan, echa un vistazo a la documentación de Laravel. Sí tiene implementadas las opciones de Programación de tareas, además integradas en la propia aplicación (con todas las ventajas que tiene), así que podrías programar un controlador que se ejecute, por ejemplo, a las 09.00 todos los días para los que se han dado de alta 15 días antes.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

La documentación está bastante completa y no es una herramienta demasiado complicada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo crearía un comando de Laravel que busque los usuarios registrados hace dos semanas. Y a cada usuario le mandas el email con el enlace a su enquesta.

Luego en el fichero del kernel (app/console/kernel) puedes programar ese comando para que se ejecute una vez al día.

Los comandos, además, puedes ejecutarlos desde terminal usando artisan.